# What is with ";" at the very beginning of a js script file?

Tags: javascript

I saw a lot of (well written and useful) scripts that were beginning with the ";" character at the very beginning of the script. For example in dropzone.js:

```
;
(function () {

//script's code here

});
```

Also, I saw this in other libraries/scripts too. I know what the (function(){}) does but is there a meaning by putting the ";" there?

Comment: It does absolutely nothing. `;` is the empty statement.